# Joining data on multiple column conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have below data in a SQL table.

```
CREATE TABLE dataframe (
A int,
B int,
C int,
rate float
);

insert into dataframe (A,B,C,rate) values 
(0,0,0,0.0),
(1,0,0,0.10),
(0,1,0,0.11),
(0,0,1,0.12),
(1,1,0,0.24),
(1,0,1,0.27),
(0,1,1,0.30),
(1,1,1,0.40)
```

A,B and C are my channels with values - 0 or 1, hence there are 8 rows in the table. I am calculating an additional 'total' column by computing row wise total -

```
select *, (d.A + d.B + d.C) as total,
from dataframe d

A   B   C   rate    total
0   0   0   0       0
1   0   0   0.1     1
0   1   0   0.11    1
0   0   1   0.12    1
1   1   0   0.24    2
1   0   1   0.27    2
0   1   1   0.3     2
1   1   1   0.4     3
```

A, B and C have individual probabilities as below -

```
select d.A, d.B , d.C, rate as individual_probabilties
from dataframe d 
where d.A + d.B + d.C = 1

A   B   C   individual_probabilities
1   0   0   0.1
0   1   0   0.11
0   0   1   0.12
```

But I am interested in pair-wise occurrence probabilities given by below query -

```
select d.A, d.B , d.C, rate as paired_probabilities
from dataframe d 
where d.A + d.B + d.C = 2

A   B   C   paired_probabilities
1   1   0   0.24
1   0   1   0.27
0   1   1   0.3
```

I want to append multiple columns to this paired_probabilities table which shows output as below -

```
A   B   C   paired_probabilities    individual_prob_A   individual_prob_B   individual_prob_C
1   1   0   0.24                    0.1                      0.11                 0
1   0   1   0.27                    0.1                       0                  0.12                     
0   1   1   0.3                     0                        0.11                0.12
```

To make thing clearer, the first row of output result shows A=1, B=1, C=0. Hence the individual probabilities for A=0.1, B=0.11 and C=0 is appended to the table data respectively.
Similarly, for second row, A=1, B=0, C=1 shows individual probabilities for A=0.1, B=0 and C=0.12 is appended to the table data respectively.

Kindly help.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: hey, I edited the question with the database that I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to think about your question is that you need to left join the rate from the row where only A=1 to all of the data where A=1, and then repeat that process for B and C. This is what it looks like:

```
select 
  d.A, 
  d.B , 
  d.C, 
  d.rate as paired_probabilities,
  coalesce(da.rate,0) as individual_prob_A,
  coalesce(db.rate,0) as individual_prob_B,
  coalesce(dc.rate,0) as individual_prob_C
from 
  dataframe d 
left join
  (select * from dataframe where A = 1 and A+B+C=1) da
  on d.A = 1
left join
  (select * from dataframe where B = 1 and A+B+C=1) db
  on d.B = 1
left join
  (select * from dataframe where C = 1 and A+B+C=1) dc
  on d.C = 1
where 
  d.A + d.B + d.C = 2
```

Comment: To match your desired output exactly, you would also need to coalesce the null values to 0.

Comment: can you help with query for handling null values to 0?

Comment: I edited the answer. The coalesce statement simply takes the first non-null parameter. select coalesce(null,1) will return 1. coalesce(2,1) will return 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with window functions or aggregation:

```
select t.*,
       (case when a > 0 
             then max(case when a = 1 and b = 0 and c = 0 then rate end) over ()
        end) as a_individual,
       (case when b > 0 
             then max(case when a = 0 and b = 1 and c = 0 then rate end) over ()
        end) as b_individual,
       (case when c > 0 
             then max(case when a = 0 and b = 0 and c = 1 then rate end) over ()
        end) as c_individual
from t;
```

Comment: can you please explain the over() function ?

Comment: @Regressor . . . It is not a function; it is the syntax for window functions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql).  These should have better performance than a `join` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using  Cartesian product

```
WITH CountData AS 
(

  SELECT
  A , B , C , rate
  FROM dataframe  
   WHERE A + B + C = 2
 )
 ,ProbData AS 
 (
   SELECT
   A , B , C , rate
  FROM dataframe  
   WHERE A + B + C = 1
  ) 

  SELECT  
     a.A,a.b,a.c,MAX(a.rate) AS  probabilities,
     MAX(CASE WHEN a.A = 1 AND  b.A = 1 and b.B = 0 and b.C = 0  THEN b.rate ELSE 0 END) AS individual_prob_A,     
      MAX(CASE WHEN a.B = 1 AND  b.A = 0 and b.B = 1 and b.C = 0  THEN b.rate ELSE 0 END) AS individual_prob_B,
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.C = 1 AND  b.A = 0 and b.B = 0 and b.C = 1 THEN b.rate ELSE 0 END) AS individual_prob_C
  FROM CountData AS a , ProbData AS b
  GROUP BY a.A,a.b,a.c
```